# ARKit dragging object changes scale

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit, scnnode

İ am trying to move the SCNNode object which i placed on to a surface. İt moves but the scale changes and it becomes smaller, when i first start to move.

This is what i did;

```
@IBAction func dragBanana(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let _ = self.sceneView.session.currentFrame else {return}

    if(sender.state == .began) {
        let location = sender.location(in: self.sceneView)
        let hitTestResult = sceneView.hitTest(location, options: nil)
        if !hitTestResult.isEmpty {
            guard let hitResult = hitTestResult.first else {return}
            movedObject = hitResult.node
        }
    }
    if (sender.state == .changed) {
        if(movedObject != nil) {
            let location = sender.location(in: self.sceneView)
            let hitTestResult = sceneView.hitTest(location, types: .existingPlaneUsingExtent)
            guard let hitResult = hitTestResult.first else {return}
            let matrix = SCNMatrix4(hitResult.worldTransform)
            let vector = SCNVector3Make(matrix.m41, matrix.m42, matrix.m43)
            movedObject?.position = vector
        }
    }
    if (sender.state == .ended) {
        movedObject = nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer is probably very late, but I faced this issue myself and it took me a while to kind of figure out why this might happen. I'll share my experience and maybe you can relate to it.

My problem was that I was trying to change the position of the node after changing its scale at runtime (most of my 3D assets were very large when added, I scale them down with a pinch gesture). I noticed changing the scale was the cause of the position change not working as expected.

I found a very simple solution to this. You simply need to change this line:

```
movedObject?.position = vector
```

to this:

```
movedObject?.worldPosition = vector
```

According to `SCNNode` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/), the `position` property determines the position of the node relative to its parent. While `worldPosition` is the position of the node relative to the scene's root node (i.e. the world origin of `ARSCNView`)

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score -2):

It's because you're moving the object on the 3 axis and Z changes that's why it feels like it scales but it's only getting closer to you.